# ¿Qué ocurre con este código, por qué PHP dice que la cadena es igual a cero?

Tags: php, string

No entiendo lo que ocurre en este código... ¿por qué mi PHP me dice que la cadena es igual a `0`? ¿Es un bug de mi PHP?

### Código:

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;

if($loremIpsum==$cero){
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Salida:

```
Lorem ipsum es igual a 0
```

### Código:

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero="Lorem ipsum";

if($loremIpsum==$cero){
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Salida:

```
Lorem ipsum es igual a Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Realmente esto sólo pasa cuando tienes como variable numérica a comparar el valor 0 (en tu caso $cero=0) porque PHP al no encontrar una equivalencia numérica en el string $loremIpsum termina asignandole por defecto el valor de 0. Si hubieses comparado con $cero=1 por ejemplo la condición nunca se cumpliría porque $loremIpsum en la conversión de tipos sigue teniendo como valor 0. Lo explico más detallado en mi respuesta. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No es un bug, es la manera en la cual se puede interpretar la condicional.
Si comparas con doble igual "==" puedes comparar con boolean, int, float, valores numéricos.
Para comparar de manera correcta un string puede utilizar "===" (para una comparación estricta).

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;

if($loremIpsum===$cero){
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Al comparar cualquier string indiferentemente de su longitud lo más conveniente es utilizar una condición estricta. Ya que internamente el string, al compararlo con un valor numérico, éste es parseado. En pocas palabras tu código se comporta así.

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;

if(intval($loremIpsum)==$cero){
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que PHP convierte el string a entero para hacer la comparación? ¿Sabes a qué se debería eso? Hay cosas de PHP que me sorprenden realmente.

Comment: Lo que hace el operador "===" es comparar si una variable es del mismo tipo (String, Int, Float, etc) que la otra y a su vez compara si el contenido es el mismo.

Comment: Al no ser del mismo tipo de dato, PHP interpreta la comparación como una comparación de enteros. Por eso existe el === para que además de comparar el valor, compare el tipo de dato. Aca puedes ver unos ejemplos:
http://php.net/manual/es/types.comparisons.php#type.comparisons-strict

Answer (score 3):

Esto se debe a como funciona el [Operadores de comparación (`==`)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

> Si se compara un número con un `string` o la comparación implica `strings` numéricos, entonces cada `string` es convertido en un número y la comparación realizada numéricamente.

¿Como funciona la [conversión de string a números](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)?

> El valor es dado por la parte inicial del string. Si el string empieza con un dato numérico válido, éste será el valor empleado. De lo contrario, el valor será 0 (cero). Un dato numérico válido es un signo opcional, seguido de uno o más dígitos (opcionalmente puede contener un punto decimal), seguido de un exponente opcional. El exponente es una 'e' o 'E' seguida de uno o más dígitos.

Es decir, que se la comparación es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
$loremIpsum = (int) "Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;

if ($loremIpsum==$cero) {
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: El string es convertido a su equivalencia númerica (si es que la posee). Ejemplo: `$a="1000"` se convierte de cadena a int con el valor 1000 quedando así $a=1000, sin embargo, si PHP no encuentra equivalencia númerica le asigna por defecto el valor de "0". Ejemplo: $b="esto es una cadena" luego de la conversión de tipos pasa a ser $b=0.

Comment: @Huskie, he actualizado mi respuesta, para dejar mas claro el funcionamiento de la _conversión de `string` a número_

Answer (score 2):

Abundando en las respuestas anteriores, hay otros tipos de conversión implícita que pueden llevar a casos curiosos. Por ejemplo, un booleano comparado con un número mediante `==` convierte el número 0 en `false` y otros números en `true` de manera que si haces el siguiente flujo de comparaciones:

```
<?php
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;
$falso = false;

if($loremIpsum == $cero){
    echo '$loremIpsum es igual a $cero'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$loremIpsum es distinto a $cero'.PHP_EOL;
}


if($cero == $falso){
    echo '$cero es igual a $falso'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$cero es distinto a $falso'.PHP_EOL;
}

if($falso == $loremIpsum) {
    echo '$falso es igual a $loremIpsum'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$falso es distinto a $loremIpsum'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Tienes como respuesta:

```
$loremIpsum es igual a $cero
$cero es igual a $falso
$falso es distinto a $loremIpsum
```

Lo cual rompería la transitividad.

Comment: Como te comenté en tu respuesta, no es necesario que todos los caracteres sean numéricos. El string `123hola` es `==` al número 123

Answer (score 2):

He leído las demás respuestas pero he notado que no se ha detallado algo importante con respecto a la **conversión de tipos** a la hora de utilizar el operador de comparación "flexible" (`$a==$b` por ejemplo) de **PHP**.

Cuando se utiliza el **operador de comparación flexible** entre una cadena de texto (tipo string) y un número (tipo int por ejemplo) **PHP** automáticamente convierte la cadena de texto a un valor númerico exactamente igual a "0" para poder realizar la comparación con el otro número ya que este **operador** se encarga de evaluar el valor de ambas variables cuando estas poseen el mismo tipo (nummérica ambas).

Es necesario que quede claro que **PHP** no convierte a cualquier número la variable que posee una cadena de texto y que se desea comparar con un número cualquiera. Realmente el proceso chequea si ya era un número, de ser así pues toma como valor el número exactamente como estaba expresado en la cadena de texto. De otra forma al no poder convertir este valor a númerico (porque la cadena de texto no posee ningún caracter numérico) inmediatamente este es convertido a "0" para poder realizar una comparación de los valores siendo el tipo de ambas variables igual.

Es por ello que este condicional (**if**) si se cumple:

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum"; // En la conversión de tipos $loremIpsum=0
$cero=0;

if($loremIpsum==$cero){ // 0=0 por eso es que entra en el condicional
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Mientras que en este otro no:

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum"; // En la conversión de tipos $loremIpsum=0
$uno=1;

if($loremIpsum==$uno){ // 0!=1 y es por ello que no entra en el condicional
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$uno.PHP_EOL;
}
```

No entra en el condicional porque `$loremIpsum` en la conversión de tipos tendrá como valor "0" y 0 es diferente de 1 (valor de $uno) evidentemente.

Como mencionan los otros usuarios para solventar esto existe justamente el comparador estricto (===) de PHP que comparará tanto el tipo como el contenido de ambas variables (sin niguna conversión de tipos implicita):

```
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
$cero=0;

if($loremIpsum===$cero){
    echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "No son iguales"; // Entra en este condicional
}
```

Para ampliar un poco más la información puedes visitar [Comparación Flexible y Comparación Estricta](https://programarivm.com/comparacion-flexible-y-estricta-en-php/).

**Observación:**

**1)** Si tenemos:

```
$a="cadena de texto";
$b=0

 if($a==$b){ // 0=0
     echo "Cero es igual a Cero" // Entra en condicional
 }
```

La variable `$a` será convertida a númerica y se le otorgará el valor de 0 debido a que la cadena de texto no posee equivalente númerico.

**2)** Si tenemos:

```
$a="2500";
$b=0

 if($a==$b){ // 2500!=0
     echo "Cero es igual a Cero" // No entró en condicional
 }
```

La variable `$a` será convertida a su equivalencia númerica y debido a que la cadena de texto posee caracteres númericos se le es asignado justo el valor de los números encontrados en la misma cuando se hace la conversión de tipos a númerica por lo que el nuevo valor de `$a` será de 2500

Espero sea de utilidad. Un Saludo!

Comment: No es necesario que la cadena consista en puros valores numéricos. El string `'123hola'` es `==` al número 123. La conversión implícita de string a número lee el string hasta que encuentra un caracter no numérico

Comment: Actualizada mi respuesta. Gracias Amenadiel

Answer (score 1):

Primer punto la comparación la debes hacer con triple signo igual, como te muestro a continuación:

```
<?php    
$loremIpsum="Lorem ipsum";
    $cero=0;

    if($loremIpsum===$cero){
        echo $loremIpsum." es igual a ".$cero.PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo "no son iguales";
    }
```

¿Qué ocurre o por que se presenta esta situación?

tenemos tres operadores:

= que me sirve para asignar un valor a una variable, ejemplo:

```
$numero = 12;
```

== que me sirve para comparar si un valor es igual a otro en razón de su tipo

=== que me ayuda a identificar si un valor es igual y del mismo tipo

te dejo la recomendación de implementar el último ya que vuelve mas estricta la comparació

Saludos