# ¿Es normal este comportamiento en switch?

Tags: php

### El caso

Resulta que haciendo unos test me he encontrado con un comportamiento algo inusual o que antes no había experimentado.

El tema es que la función [*switch*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) permite hacer comparaciones de forma consecutiva del tipo:

```
//...
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 'a':
    echo "...";
    break;
//...
```

En el [manual de php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) aparecen ejemplos similares.

La teoría es que si el valor de `$i` es `0`, `1`, o `a` debería activar el `echo`.

En el caso que muestro:

- Los valores `0` o `a` retornarían `0`.
- Los valores `1` o `b` retornarían `1`.
- Los valores `2` o `c` retornarían `2`.

Pero no se que motivo hace que no de los resultados esperados con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class Test {
    const A = 0;
    const B = 1;
    const C = 2;

    public function select($value)
    {
        switch($value) {
            case 'a':
            case self::A:
                return self::A;
                break;
            case 'b':
            case self::B:
                return self::B;
                break;
            case 'c':
            case self::C:
                return self::C;
                break;
            default:
                return 3;
        }
    }
}

$test = new Test();
echo $test->select('b');
```

Un ejemplo funcional en un [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0598d709909892594d5aa3136e9e1f2653f1bbc9).

### El problema

> Todos los *integer* retornan su valor correcto, pero los *strings* siempre retornan `0`.

### La pregunta

¿Por qué motivo los valores con `string` no retornan el valor que le corresponde?

Comment: No es un problema del `switch` en sí mismo, sino de **la forma en que PHP hace las comparaciones**. [Yo plantée una pregunta con un problema similiar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139550/29967)... la conclusión fue que al hacer una comparación *no estricta* de una cadena, ésta es parseada a `int`, y termina siendo convertida en un `cero (0)`.

Comment: @A.Cedano eso estoy viendo. Ni me había planteado que podía ser eso. Gracias por comentar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema viene de una conversión de tipos, en la documentación podemos encontrar lo siguiente:

[Operadores de comparación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Si se compara un número con un string o la comparación implica strings numéricos, entonces cada string es convertido en un número y la comparación realizada numéricamente. Estas reglas también se aplican a la sentencia switch. La conversión de tipo no tiene lugar cuando la comparación es === o !== ya que esto involucra comparar el tipo así como el valor.

### ¿Qué esta sucediendo?

Primero veamos que sucede cuando forzamos el String `b` a número

```
$value = 'b';
echo (int) $value; // 0
```

Sí vemos la [documentación de Conversión de string a números](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) vemos lo siguiente:

> El valor es dado por la parte inicial del string. Si el string empieza con un dato numérico válido, éste será el valor empleado. **De lo contrario, el valor será 0 (cero)**.

Por lo tanto si repasamos el `switch` y los reultados el ejemplo:

```
class Test {
    const A = 0;
    const B = 1;
    const C = 2;

    public function select($value)
    {  
      switch($value) {
        case 'a':  // a == b : false
        case self::A:  // 0 == 0 : true
            return self::A;
            break;
        case 'b':  // b == b : true
        case self::B:  // 1 == 0 : false
            return self::B;
            break;
        case 'c': // c == b : false
        case self::C: // 3 == 0 : false
            return self::C;
            break;
        default:
            return 3;
      }
    }
}
```

### ¿Cómo  resolverlo?

Para mi la forma más apropiada es forzar a strings en el case, ya que podríamos recibir números como string y si forzamos tipos estas comparacion estricta será false (`string '1'=== int 1 : false`).

Ejemplo:

```
    switch($value) {
        case 'a':  // a == b : false
        case (string) self::A:  // b == 0 : false
            return self::A;
            break;
        case 'b':  // b == b : true
        case (string) self::B:  // b == 0 : false
            return self::B;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Super claro!! Me tenía esto enredado toda la mañana y no terminaba de ver donde estaba el error. Gracias por el aporte.

Comment: @OscarR Te añado una forma de solucionarlo, justo estaba editando.

Comment: Pasa los test perfectamente Xerif. Muchas gracias por la info.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo solucionaras, es posible que la respuesta contenga algun error de formato o ortografía, respondí desde el móvil, si detectais alguno invito a que lo corrijáis como Cedano hizo, gracias.

Answer (score 4):

El problema puede estar en que, según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)  la sentencia switch/case funciona con comparaciones flexibles. con lo que esto supone a la hora de comparar cadenas.

Puedes ver un poco más de información en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152477/7478)

Una manera de resolverlo es "forzando" a que haga comparaciones estrictas:

```
 class Test {
        const A = 0;
        const B = 1;
        const C = 2;

        public function select($value)
        {

            switch($value) {
                case 'a':
                case $value === self::A:
                    return self::A;
                    break;
                case 'b':

                case $value === self::B:
                    return self::B;
                    break;
                case 'c':
                case $value === self::C:
                    return self::C;
                    break;
                default:
                    return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    $test = new Test();
    echo $test->select('c');
```

Comment: lo mismo. Acabo de actualizar y veo que ya han dado respuesta... :)

Comment: Genial Ernesto. Como comentaba en la pregunta, ni me había planteado que podía ser eso. Gracias por la respuesta! En el mismo tiempo estaban respondiendo y dando solución por el chat

Comment: Ernesto, cambio la respuesta aceptada. La respuesta de Xerif se adapta mejor a los diferentes test con distintos formatos en el argumento. No obstante, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: ¡Por supuesto! !yo mismo le he dado un voto positivo a @Xerif! Encantado de ayudar